# check if function is valid to prevent 'undefined method error' in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, will-paginate

I am using a gem, will_paginate, to paginate contents on a rails site.

It's usage is: (from the official example)

```
## perform a paginated query:
@posts = Post.paginate(:page => params[:page])

# or, use an explicit "per page" limit:
Post.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 30)

## render page links in the view:
<%= will_paginate @posts %>
```

Now in some views, I will need the pagination but some views I don't. So when using a common layout to render out the content, the pages without pagination will display an error.

> will_paginate undefined method error

Is there a way to check if will_paginate is a valid function before it the view tries to display it?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: @apneadiving what do you mean?

Comment: I mean you should have an improvable organization, otherwise you wouldn't face that kind of issue. Too much factorization is sometimes meaningless

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of `rescue`. 
For example :

```
<%= do_something rescue do_something_else %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `defined? will_paginate` or `will_paginate @posts rescue _do_something_else_`.
The `defined?` tells you if the function is defined, any you can use it in an if, the `rescue` handles the exception.